# Java multi-threads programming

Tags: java

I am a beginner of Java programming learner. I can't know how to correct the following Java program. Kindly help to let me know how to correct it. Thanks a lot.

public class TMA1Q2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Usage: java TMA1Q2 {number of Threads}");

    // Create tasks
    Runnable taskA = new PrintTwoConcurThreads("Thread A ");
    Runnable taskB = new PrintTwoConcurThreads("            Thread B ");

    // Create threads
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(taskA);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(taskB);

    // Start threads
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```

}

// The task that implements Runnable

```
class PrintTwoConcurThreads implements Runnable {

private final String TwoConcurThreads;
private String[] args;

public PrintTwoConcurThreads(String numThreads) {
    TwoConcurThreads = numThreads;
}

// Override the run() method
@Override
public void run() {
    // Print the value input argument times
    int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Thread[] myThread;
    myThread = new Thread[numThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        System.out.println(TwoConcurThreads + i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do. I can see `Thread[]` is useless.

Comment: Kindly see the problem after debugging:
Usage: java TMA1Q2 {number of Threads}
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PrintTwoConcurThreads.run(TMA1Q2.java:38)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PrintTwoConcurThreads.run(TMA1Q2.java:38)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: I want to write a program with two concurrent threads. The Two threads write "Thread A X" and "Thread B X" on screen respectively where X takes on successive values from 0 to n - 1 where n is the argument used to run program. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user3079494, edit the question; include the error that you receive and what you are trying to achieve. That will make it easier for people to help you and will make the question more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String[] args;
```

This `args` field is never initialized, so it will be having a default value of `null`.

When you try to access it in following line you get a `NullPointerException`

```
int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

It is not clear what you're trying to do. Atleast this would help you to see what's going wrong.

Also I have no Idea why following lines are used, You create `Thread[]` but never you used it.

```
Thread[] myThread;
myThread = new Thread[numThreads];
```

Comment: Yes, I have also no idea because I am a fresh learner and just read from a reference book to try. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I try to write a program with two concurrent threads. The two threads write "Thread A X" and "Thread B X" on screen respectively where X takes on successive values from 0 to n - 1 where n is the argument used to run program. Thank you so much.

Comment: The output screen likes below:

Comment: Thread A 0 
  Thread B 0
Thread A 1
Thread A 2
  Thread B 1
Thread A 3  
  Thread B 2
Thread A 4
  Thread B 3
  Thread B 4
Thread A 5 
  Thread B 5

Comment: Please try the following program. It can works but I don't know how to the argument used to run the program.

Comment: public class TMA1Q2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println("Usage: java TMA1Q2 {number of Threads}");

        // Create tasks
        Runnable taskA = new PrintTwoConcurThreads("Thread A ");
        Runnable taskB = new PrintTwoConcurThreads("            Thread B ");

        // Create threads
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(taskA);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(taskB);

        // Start threads
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}

Comment: // The task that implements Runnable
class PrintTwoConcurThreads implements Runnable {

    private final String TwoConcurThreads;
    private String[] args;

    public PrintTwoConcurThreads(String numThreads) {
        TwoConcurThreads = numThreads;
    }

    // Override the run() method
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Print the value input argument times
        // int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
            System.out.println(TwoConcurThreads + i);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @user3079494 Do you expect someone to make sense of the code (which you don't understand yourself) in those two comments?

Comment: @user3079494 You have used `numThreads` is two different ways, nether has anything to do with "number of threads" which you have fixed as 2. I suggest you learn how to write this code with just one thread before you make it much more complicated by getting multiple threads to work as you expected.